# can Haskell compiler give warning on functions that used "undefined"

Tags: haskell

If I define a function using "undefined" like this, it type-checks.

```
add2 :: Int -> Int -> Int
add2 = undefined
```

Is it possible to detect if any function is using "undefined" in the function definition, and turn it into a warning?

It would be useful that in development-phase, I can use "undefined" to check if the type signature is correct before I implement the function. And then on production I can have some way to catch the mistakes that I forgot to give implementation for functions that had "undefined".

Comment: Why not perform a `grep` over the source code? `undefined` would be a very strange variable name.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It’s much easier to mechanically enforce zero warnings in CI (with `-Werror`), and a warning will integrate nicely with editor tooling that already handles compiler warnings. Manually `grep`ing is much more ad-hoc.

Comment: @AlexisKing correct me if wrong, I don't think GHC has any option to warn the usage of `undefined`, and this is what @willem-van-onsem is trying to solve. Although I learned the typed holes is a better way than `undefined` to achieve what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A good solution is to use typed holes instead of `undefined` along with the `-fdefer-typed-holes` compiler flag to make them warnings instead of errors (which is generally more useful, anyway). With this flag enabled, you would write your example like this, instead:

```
add2 :: Int -> Int -> Int
add2 = _
```

…which produces the following warning:

```
warning: [-Wtyped-holes]
    • Found hole: _ :: Int -> Int -> Int
    • In the expression: _
      In an equation for ‘add2’: add2 = _
    • Relevant bindings include
        add2 :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

Modern GHCs will even include a list of possible substitutions for the hole in the warning:

```
      Valid substitutions include
        add2 :: Int -> Int -> Int
        (+) :: forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a
          (imported from ‘Prelude’ (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Num’))
        (*) :: forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a
          (imported from ‘Prelude’ (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Num’))
        (^) :: forall a b. (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a
          (imported from ‘Prelude’ (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Real’))
        (-) :: forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a
          (imported from ‘Prelude’ (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Num’))
        seq :: forall a b. a -> b -> b
          (imported from ‘Prelude’ (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Prim’))
        (Some substitutions suppressed; use -fmax-valid-substitutions=N or -fno-max-valid-substitutions)
```

Answer (score 4):

Some alternative preludes export their own version of `undefined` with warning added so you will see warning during compilation if you left `undefined`.

- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/relude-0.2.0/docs/Relude-Debug.html#v:undefined

Comment: It's worth pointing out that if you look at the source you'll see that it's just `undefined = Prelude.undefined`; the new definition allows them to add a warning pragma, so you could easily make your own version of undefined that does this. The virtue of it being in a custom prelude is that you generally set up a whole project to use it, which makes it harder to accidentally use the standard version instead of the new one (which wouldn't trigger the warning).

Answer (score 3):

If You are using [`hlint`](https://github.com/ndmitchell/hlint), You can add this rule to your `.hlint.yaml`:

```yaml
- warning: {lhs: "undefined", rhs: undefined}
```

for warnings like:

> Use alternative. Replace with: undefined

or You can add your own description with `name` attribute, for example:

```yaml
- warning: {lhs: "undefined", rhs: undefined, name: Realisation is required}
```

> Realisation is required. Replace with: undefined

You can use [automatic refactoring](https://github.com/ndmitchell/hlint#automatically-applying-hints) safely, because of it just replace `undefined` to `undefined` and does not broke anything.

Also You can ignore this rule (with `name` attribute) for specific function:

```haskell
{-# ANN functionName "HLint: ignore Realisation is required" #-}
functionName :: Int -> Int
functionName x = undefined
```

or for module: `{-# ANN module "HLint: ignore Realisation is required" #-}`